# DataFrameの結合について

Tags: python, pandas

異なる行インデックスを持っている行の結合の方法について。

下記のような場合どうすればいいのか教えてください。

①DataFrame1
日付データと特徴量が複数入っています（2001年～）
↓
②DataFrame1をmatrixに変換
scikit-learnの機械学習モデルをつかってpreditするため　
"2008年"からの特徴量のみを抽出しmatrix化後predictにかけます。
↓
③日付とpredict結果の結合
見やすさのためにDataFrame1の日付とpredictの結果（matrix）を結合したいのですが、
前者にはおおもとのDataFrameに振られている行インデックスがふられている一方で、
後者は行インデックスが0からスタートになっているため、
結合すると行がずれます（日付だけまとまって下にかたまってでる。）

どうすればよいでしょうか？なお、結合は下記でやっています。

```
i_date = df['date']
i_pred = pd.Series(gr.predict(X_test))
df2 = pd.concat([i_date,i_pred], axis=1)
```

※dfが元のDataFrame①にあたります。grが機械学習モデルです。
　X_testは元のDataFrame①から抽出した特徴量のmatrixです。

Answer (score 1):

i_pred の Indexに 元のdfのIndexを設定する方法

```
i_date = df['date']
i_pred = pd.Series(gr.predict(X_test), index=df.index)
df2 = pd.concat([i_date,i_pred], axis=1)
```

i_date 側のIndex値を0 から振りなおす方法

```
i_date = df['date'].reset_index(drop=True)
i_pred = pd.Series(gr.predict(X_test))
df2 = pd.concat([i_date,i_pred], axis=1)
```

あたりでいかがでしょうか。